# Python : Sort a dictionary by using keys in ascending order

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary and I want to order it in ascending using the keys.

```
animMeshes = { "anim 0" : 23, "anim 32": 4, "anim 21" : 5, "anim 2" : 66, "anim 11" : 7 , "anim 1" : 5}
```

I tried using :

```
for mesh,val in sorted(animMeshes.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]):
    print mesh
```

o/p :

```
anim 0
anim 1
anim 11
anim 2
anim 21
anim 32
```

How could I get :

```
anim 0
anim 1
anim 2
anim 11
anim 21
anim 32
```

Answer (score 3):

For your specific case, this can work:

```
for mesh,val in sorted(animMeshes.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[0].split()[1])):
    print mesh
```

Why? because your keys all start with 'anim' and then have a number...

I used a conversion to `int()` for the sorting by number behaviour.

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with it being a dictionary, and only to do with the fact that `str(10) < str(2)`, but `int(10) > int(2)`.

Comment: @JLLagrange, good point. Sometimes pointing out the obvious should be the first thing to do! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to split the key and sort based on the integer value of the number part, like this

```
for mesh, val in sorted(animMeshes.items(), key=lambda t: int(t[0].split()[1])):
    print mesh
```

**Output**

```
anim 0
anim 1
anim 2
anim 11
anim 21
anim 32
```